# Strange exception thrown in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor

Today i encountered a strange status page exception being thrown in Ktor.

I am trying to build a simple api with ktor and i did this Route:

```
fun Route.phrase(db : Repository){
post(PHRASE_ENDPOINT){
    val request = call.receive<Request>()
    val phrase = db.add(EmojiPhrase(request.toString(), request.toString()))
    this.call.respond(phrase)
   }}
```

when i try to send the request i get
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.io.ByteReadChannel**

has anyone encountered this problem

im using :

```
    ktor_version=1.3.2, 
    kotlin_version=1.4.10, 
    moshi_version= 1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue appears to be in moshi converter: https://github.com/rharter/ktor-moshi/issues/7#issuecomment-580977097

> Until the PR is merged, you can use the patched version through
> jitpack
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
>         maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
>     }
> }
> dependencies {
>     implementation 'com.github.cs125-illinois:ktor-moshi:7252ca49ed'
> }
> ```